# If haystack returns an object, why can't I use result.objects.get_absolute_url

Tags: django, python-3.x, solr, django-haystack

I'm using haystack and I follow the tutorials. I add haystack to settings, migrate, then I  create this

```
class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
  text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
  publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')

  def get_model(self):
      return Post

  def index_queryset(self, using=None):
      """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
      return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

in templates I create

```
search/indexes/blog/post_text.txt
```

and add this to it

```
{{ object.title }}
{{ object.tags.all|join:", " }}
{{ object.body }}
```

in my views.py i add

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
```

then in a view function

```
def post_search(request):

  form = request.GET.get('q')
  results = SearchQuerySet().models(Post).filter(content=form)
  # count total results
  total_results = results.count()
  template = 'blog/post/search.html',
  context = {
      'form': form,
      'results': results,
      'total_results': total_results

  }
  return render(request, template, context)
```

and in a search template

```
{% for result in results %}
  <p>{{result.publish}}</p>

  <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">{{ result.object.title }}</a>
```

but the only thing that gets returned is the publish. If I inspect the a element the href is blank. if I do this

```
{{results}}
```

I get something like this

```
[blog.post.pk(2)] or something like that
```

these will not work

```
 {{result.object.publish}}<br>
```

but this will
     {{result.publish}}

and to access these

```
 {{result.object.body}}<br>
 {{result.object.title}}<br>
 {{result.object.slug}}<br>
```

I go back and add this

```
 class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
  text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
  publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')

  # added this
  title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
  body = indexes.CharField(model_attr='body')
  slug = indexes.CharField(model_attr='slug')

  def get_model(self):
      return Post

  def index_queryset(self, using=None):
      """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
      return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

which is nothing like the the tutorials say What am I doing wrong?

I get my results buy doing this

```
result.title
```

not

```
result.object.title
```

and from the tutorials I watch and read all they do is this

```
 class PostIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
  text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
  publish = indexes.DateTimeField(model_attr='publish')

  def get_model(self):
      return Post

  def index_queryset(self, using=None):
      """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
      return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

but can access everything like this

```
result.object.title
result.object.publish
result.object.get_absolute_url
```

they are obviously accessing the whole object but for some reason I am not. any guidance or a suggestion to something that I could possibly see like a video 
would be appreciated. I really don't get why I'm not accessing the whole object.

Edit :

my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):

STATUS_CHOICES = (
   ('draft', 'Draft'),
   ('published', 'Published'),
)
title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,
                        unique_for_date='publish')
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(User,
                           related_name='blog_posts')
body = models.TextField()
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                          choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
                          default='draft')
video = models.BooleanField(default=False)
video_path = models.CharField(max_length=320,
                              null=True,
                              blank=True,)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('-publish',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                       args=[self.publish.year,
                             self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                             self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                             self.slug])

objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager.
tags = TaggableManager()
```

I'm using

```
Django==1.9.4
django-crispy-forms==1.6.0
django-haystack==2.4.1
django-taggit==0.18.0
Pillow==3.1.1
pysolr==3.4.0
pytz==2016.1
requests==2.9.1
python 3.5
```

Ive updated and rebuilt my schema and I followed Mike Hibbert and read a book called django by example follwed them verbatim and still cant figure it out. Is this some kinf=d of bug?

Comment: I think you have to define this method on your model. Haystack can't guess the url by itself, so you should build the url with `reverse()` and return it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. None of the videos I've watched have done what you said nor any of the tuts i've read

Comment: After a quick search, I've found someone with the same problem as you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27968892/haystack-whoosh-result-object-get-absolute-url-is-not-working. I guess the documentation needs an update.

Comment: thanks again for the response. This is what I already had defined             def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('blog:post_detail',
                           args=[self.publish.year,
                                 self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                                 self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                                 self.slug])

Comment: @AntoineFontaine I added my models.py so you could see what I already had. maybe you can see the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after researching this for about 3 day now, I have come across information that django 1.9 isnt fully supported so this may be the issue hopefully. Hope this spares someone the anguish that I've went through.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar or probably even the same problem.

For some reason, reverse lookups within my get_absolute_url method failed after I'd accessed the HaystackSearchQueryset containing the results. It seemed as though the reverse mechanism didn't have any patterns to analyze ("...patterns tried: []").

Your suggestion pointing towards Django 1.9 incompatibilities helped me a lot as I just installed the [lastest master](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/tree/bb07c17c7cf2dae3e65b7f56fb2bd010fd915102) and everything seems to work just fine now.Django 1.9 compatibility was added [here](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/tree/04cc1ab8f918a0473bc3d59a47f249cf0a6e9f25) by Claude Peroz. Yay :-)